# Custom category and meta key search in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to fetch the result if keyword, category and meta value is not empty. I mean to say that if the keyword is test and city is Mumbai and category is pet then show existing results that come in these parameters. Now I am getting all the results which have in other categories too.I have two inputs , one for keyword, second for City, zip code and third one for categories drop down. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Expected result should be keyword,city under selected category.

```
$arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    's' => $keyword, 
    'paged' => $paged,
     'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' =>$cats
        )
     ),
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array( 'key' => 'city', 'value' => $query_city, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
        array( 'key' => 'country', 'value' => $query_city, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
        array( 'key' => 'postalcode', 'value' => $query_city, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
        'relation' => 'OR'),

    );     
$query = new WP_Query( $arg );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, using **'relation' => 'AND'** instead **'relation' => 'OR'** should solve your issue.

Comment: Dis you read my text?. I am talking about category and meta keys not only meta keys

Comment: Oh, sorry. I think the issue related with wrong tax_query. If $cats is array, you have to add 'operator' => 'IN' to 'tax_query' section: array('taxonomy' => 'category', 'field' => 'slug','terms' => $cats, 'operator' => 'IN'). Of course if $cats is array of term slugs.

Comment: Its is not an array of slug. It is single slug of category

Comment: I have two inputs , one for keyword, second for City, zip code and third one for categories drop down.